# Can I use Bluetooth LE (BLE) in a MS-Teams app?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, microsoft-teams

This is a very generic question: Is it possible to write a MS-Teams app that can use the Bluetooth connection to send messages over BLE?

We have created a test webapp that can connect to BLE when accessed from Chrome, but when we deploy this as a MS-Teams app we do not get access to Bluetooth.

Are there some settings/permissions that we need to tweak?

(Does anyone know what browser is being used inside the MS-Teams app to render the web-apps?)

Answer (score 0):

I got some feedback on another channel.

"...

Microsoft Teams app framework does not provide direct access to Bluetooth or the ability to communicate using Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE). Microsoft Teams apps are primarily web-based and run within a sandboxed environment, which restricts access to certain hardware features like Bluetooth for security and privacy reasons.

While it's possible to create a web-based app that can access Bluetooth when accessed from a regular browser like Chrome, the same app will not have access to Bluetooth capabilities when deployed within the Microsoft Teams app framework.

I recommend you refer to the official Microsoft Teams developer documentation for any updates related to this feature.

And to answer your last question, the Teams desktop client was developed on Electron, which uses Chromium for rendering."